# browserify error. GET http://localhost:8080/js/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, browserify

I create a bundle.js file using the following command:

```
browserify test.js -o js/bundle.js -d
```

i include it in my .ejs file using:

```
<script type="module" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
```

But there's an error in my browser's console that says:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/js/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**Edit**

This is how i am serving my files:

```
//server.js
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,'public'))); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

**Error fixed:**

I moved my bundle.js file to the public folder mentioned above in the code.

Comment: That means the server is not finding the file. There is not enough information in this question to help you.

Comment: @D.Pardal What other information should I add ?

Comment: How you're serving the files. (Your server configuration)

Comment: @D.Pardal I edited the question